# how to put string into an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

i need to put the contents of an text box that is a string into an array.

i have seen lots of people asking how to put each letter as an index in the array but i want the whole string in one index.

for context
i am making an application for a hotel booking for an assignment, it takes a name, room number and length of stay. it also stores room size with radio buttons. then there is another button and a textbox that when you type a room size (Single, double or triple) it will display how many people have book that room type and the name on the booking.

any help would be greatly appreciated. here is what i have done and i picture of what the application is meant to look like.

```
namespace Assignment2
          {
          public partial class Form1 : Form
         {
            public Form1()
           {
           InitializeComponent();
          // MessageBox.Show("Initalize");
         }
        string[] CusName = new string[150];
        int[] RNumber = new int[150];
        int[] nights = new int[150];
        string[] RSize = new string[150];
        string name;
        bool blnnumcheck;
           bool blnNightsCheck;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show("Load");

    }
    private void TxtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = TxtName.Text;

    }
    private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string  size;
        int Roomnum, night;
       blnNightsCheck = int.TryParse(txtLengthofStay.Text, out night);





        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TxtName.Text, "([a-zA-Z])"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Name Please try again");
        }

        blnnumcheck = int.TryParse(txtRoomNumber.Text, out Roomnum);
        if (!blnnumcheck )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Room Number Please try again" );
        }
       if (Roomnum >= 150)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Invalid Room Number Please try again");

       }
    }





}

}
```

[this what the completed one is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ei7C.png)

Comment: Can you post an example ?? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this seems like a homework, please tell us where you are stuck at then we will help, we are not here to solve your entire homework but just to help enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Right now I'm stuck at the part where I need to put the text on into the strings

Comment: `string[] array = new [] { textbox1.Text };`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<string> myArray = new List<string>();
myArray.Add(myTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string data = "Hello, Good Morning";
string[] stringArray = new string[]{ data };

Console.WriteLine(stringArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to create arrays, continue reading, if you don't, jump to the content below the horizontal line.

You create an int array using `int[]`, right? So if you want to create a string array, use `string[]`!

Here is more code:

```
string[] myArray = new string[10];
//add stuff into the array
myArray[0] = "Hello";
myArray[1] = "World";
//etc
```

That is simple enough, right? You can do all the things you can do with an `int` array to a `string` array.

---

**If you don't know how to create an array, start to read here**

You declare an array like this:

```
type[] array_name = new type[length];
```

And you can put stuff in the array like this:

```
array_name[index] = some_stuff;
```

Thus, you can create an array of `string`s like this:

```
string[] myArray = new string[10];
//add stuff into the array
myArray[0] = "Hello";
myArray[1] = "World";
//etc
```

Just remember, whatever type you want an array to be, write whatever type followed by `[]` and give it a name!

---

You can loop through a 2D array like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < maxX ; i++) { // maxX is the maximum index of the array in the first dimension
    for (int j = 0 ; j < maxY ; j++) {
        //you can access the array here with array[i][j]
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I store text into an array but only in one index not over multiple indexes. I think I need to have a loop because this needs to happen over and over again each time storing in the next index

Comment: Text comes with a text box there are already set up to be put into a variable

Comment: @Matt If you have a text box and want to store the text in the text box into one index of an array, just `myArray[0] = textbox.Text`

Comment: so now how would i loop that so that every time i click the button the index that get used goes up by one?